# Animating constrained/child objects

Tags: animation, keyframes, constraints, parent

What im trying to do is to animate hands with pistol. When i animate it is usefull to have pistol connected to hand when i move it around. But in actual game i'll have pistol as separate object, NOT as child of hand. I tried many approaches to key pistol positions but i havent succeded in any of them. I tried child of constraint with visual keying but as soon as i set first keys pistol gets moved relative to hand and is no longer in needed position. I want pistol to be connected to hand when i keyframe it, but i want keyframes to get world positions and rotations without relation to hand bone. Is it possible to perform somehow?

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to get kindaaa effect that i need. I have placed "child of" constraint on pistol with hand bone target. And if i place visual keyframes and then "set inverce" in constraint menu it gets right keys. Im sure that there is better solution, but as i see people here are only capable of putting "-" without replying anything.

Comment: when needing an object to be parented to another, but needing to switch parentage later, you can either switch over to a duplicate object at that frame and have that parented to the new parent, or force the same object to 'follow' the hand etc using keyframes and no parentage.  Keep the weapon's marker-Empty aligned with another that's on the hand. With Blender's graph editor, keeping the two in synch isn't all that difficult.  Whilst this introduces a manual a form of loose 'Rotoscoping', it does keep the weapon independant and unconstrained.

Comment: Further to the above - I have done what you're to achieve in Blender's game engine and for that used duplicate models that were snapped away until required, each either parented (attached) to another object, or free to be dropped or thrown later.